# css resize content to fill the height

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have three sections on my page: navbar, content and footer. But unfortunately, it doesn't fill the full height of the page, which creates a white space below the footer. How can I make the container fit responsively between the navbar and footer? I tried with media queries for the UploadPageComponent, but didn't succeed.

[image]

**App.scss**

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
}
.App {
     background-color: #F5F5F5;
     font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
     #root {
          height: 100vh;
     }
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavigationBar />
      <UploadPageComponent />
      <FooterComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**NavigationBar.scss**

```
.NavigationBar {
     background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 47% 22%,#a8a19e,#76726b);
     box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0;
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: row;
     height: 3.75em;
     -o-object-fit: contain;
     justify-content: space-between;
     object-fit: contain;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 1000;
}
```

**UploadPageComponent.scss**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1680px) {
     .UploadPageComponent {
          height: 69%;
     }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 680px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
     .UploadPageComponent {
          height: 76%;
     }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 679px) {
     .UploadPageComponent {
          height: 74%;
     }
}
```

**FooterComponent.scss**

```
.FooterComponent {
     background-image: url('../../assets/images/footer-background.png');
     background-size: cover;
     bottom: 0;
     color: #fff;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     font-size: 13px;
     min-height: 100px;
     padding: 30px 15px;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: First of all I would recommend you not to set the html height to 100%. In my opinion better use min-height 100vh. And i will try to write a simple demo for you how you can solve your problem if someone else doesn't do it befor me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex-grow to make some content expand. For example something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body{
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    nav,main,footer{
        padding: 1em;
    }

    nav{
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    main{
        background-color: rgb(0, 82, 171);
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    footer{
        background-color: green;
    }

    body{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! The last years I worked with Angular flex-layout but I switched to React and need to learn the styling itself from scratch ^^. Why is min-height: 100vh recommended instead of height: 100%?

Comment: If you set the height to 100% your page would not grow with your content and you would have to handle the overflow. But if you really don't want the page to grow than it is fine to set the height.